# If LCC (Pyton) is included in the cheapest date search API

Tags: api, amadeus

I'd like to ask a simple question about the flight cheapest date search API (`https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates`).

If the source `LCC (Pyton)` is included in the response ? Thanks
Because we wonder that if the response contains the airlines like EasyJet, Aegean Airlines etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this API doesn't include Low-cost carriers.